# Displaying a custom field

Tags: custom-field

I'm trying to display a custom field called 'my_custom_field' inside the loop:

```
$custom_array = get_post_custom( get_the_ID() );                    
echo $custom_array['my_custom_field'];
```

This code display "array". Should it not display the value of the custom field instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`get_post_custom()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) will return an array of arrays. You need:

```
echo $custom_array['my_custom_field'][0];
```

Alternatively, you can use [`get_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) with the `$single` flag as `true`:

```
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_custom_field', true );
```